# Why was the team leader question closed in favor of a much later question?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/23276/2618) was closed in favor of a question that was asked some three years later, and was itself closed as being not on topic?

How can it be a duplicate if it is actually the original? Words either mean something or they don't.

Answer (score 5):

Questions are sometimes closed as duplicates of later questions because the later question is clearly of higher quality, and/or it has better answers.

**Further Reading:**
[Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643)